# Is it possible to get a book category based on ISBN?

Tags: publications, library

Libraries organize non-fiction books in category with sub-categories, using a hierarchical system, that makes it possible to find books on a specific subject.

Is there some lookup service, for example web page or database, that can provide category with sub-categories based on a books ISBN number?

Comment: What do ISBN lookup services not provide already?

Comment: ISBN lookup, e.g. https://isbnsearch.org/isbn/055380457X, only provides title, author and publication information, but there is no characterization of the contents, thus no information about how the book could be organized in a library.

Answer (score 1):

The [Google Books API](https://developers.google.com/books/docs/v1/using) offers a `category`-field.

Example: https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:055380457X (`Business & Economics` being the category).

Another example would be [WorldCat](https://www.worldcat.org/). Just type in the ISBN in the search for books, and you will find categories or topics associated with that book. (They also have a machine-readable API, but you will need to register, as far as I know.)

But note that normally every library uses its own curated hierarchy of tags.

Comment: Thanks.  Your comments made me look up how big libraries handles this, and it appears that two systems are widely used; [Library of Congress Classification (LCC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_of_Congress_Classification) and [Dewey Decimal Classes (DCC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Dewey_Decimal_classes).  Some lookup services provide this info, like http://classify.oclc.org/classify2/ with your book as http://classify.oclc.org/classify2/ClassifyDemo?search-standnum-txt=055380457X&startRec=0.  Also https://openlibrary.org/ has this info.